# Persistent Problem: Internet may not be available

Tags: connection-issues, internet, samsung-galaxy-j7

I have a J7 (SM-J730F/DS) and noticed a while back that I can connect to WiFi but that on some networks I got the message "Internet may not be available" .... and it wasn't. This message started to appear more and more frequently and on a trip last week I could not connect to any airport, hotel or other WiFi network, with the exception of 1 network at the conference center. Upon return home, I now also get the message at home and at work. Using data roaming to get on the net is not a  problem.

I searched the web and found a number of potential fixes. I did the following:

- Reboot (didn't solve it)
- Forget network, then retry (didn't solve it)
- Switch to static IP (didn't solve it)
- Changed time/date and then back (didn't solve it)
- Cleared Cache Partition (did't solve it)
- Factory reset (didn't solve it)

I'm now out of ideas. Anyone any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score -5):

Turn off automatic updates. Google Play throttles the network.

Comment: That seems more like a comment, especially because it appears to be a wild suggestion instead of a carefully considered solution. Can you tell us how automatic updates from Google Play are linked to the problem?

Comment: Honestly, this is **a bold (and *scary*) statement** if Google Play indeed throttles the network (why, though?). We need more credible references for such a bold statement like this.

Comment: What are you saying? Of course they throttle it. All isps throttle requests when overloaded. It's just server and bandwidth management.
As to references, I'm simply commenting on my experience. Almost every time I update an app larger then 30mb, the network drops out. It only happens on Google Play.